# I'm trying to use listView builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I keep getting this error when trying to use ListView. How do I fix it?

Error: The element type 'String' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. (list_element_type_not_assignable at [app_with_text] lib\main.dart:40)

code:

```
class Msg extends StatelessWidget {
  const Msg({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // User string(s)
    String user_msg = "user";

    // bot strings
    String friends = "";
    String quotes = "";
    String pfps = "";

    return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

         ListView(
         children: [friends, quotes, pfps],
         );

          const TextField(
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Password',
            ),
          )
        ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Midhun MP answer is ok, but I'm answering based on question title and next issue will occur.

`ListView` takes widgets  on `children` and  `ListView.builder` works the same way on `itemBuilder`.

The next issue you will occur unbounded height. To fix this,  you can wrap the `ListView` with `Expanded` or use `shrinkWrap: true,`. Also I will suggest moving strings outside of `build` methods if you make it  `StateFullWidget`

Here is using  `ListView.builder`

```dart
class Msg extends StatelessWidget {
  const Msg({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // User string(s)
    String user_msg = "user";

    // bot strings
    String friends = "A";
    String quotes = "B";
    String pfps = "C";

    final items = [user_msg, friends, quotes, pfps];

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        // Expanded( // dont need while using `shrinkWrap:true` , based on your UI
        //   child:
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(
              items[index],
            );
          },
        ),
        // ),
        const TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Password',
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

More about [ListView builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html)

Answer (score 1):

The children property of ListView expects a list of widgets. In your code you are passing list of strings. Create text widgets using the strings you have and pass it.

```
ListView(
  children: [
    Text(friends),
    Text(quotes),
    Text(pfps),
  ],
),
```

Read more about [ListView and it's properties](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html)